# tableview contents appear only after scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am writing a project about tableView, whose cell height is calculated according to the content of cell.

After I run the project, nothing appears on the screen but, if I scroll the screen, the contents appear.

I checked that although nothing appears on the screen, the contentView is there and the cell height is correct.

Could somebody tell me why this happens? [image: tableViewController image]

Comment: Try to add NSLog(@"%lu", self.arrayData.count); in your `viewDidAppear` method and run. Project may work after you add my line. If not, give me the printed number

Comment: The problem has not been solved yet. And it printed number 9, which is the correct number in my model.

Comment: How about call `[self.tableView reloadData]` in `viewDidLoad`?

Comment: If it doesn't work, let set a debug at `heightForRowAtIndexPath` and check what is cell height before your `tableView` scrolls

Comment: No, that doesn't help.

Comment: Did you check `heightForRowAtIndexPath`?

Comment: I have tried to print the  cellForRowAtIndexPath method and heightForRowAtIndexPath method. These two methods all worked bofore scrolling and cellForRowAtIndexPath first.

Comment: No, i mean value of `heightForRowAtIndexPath`. Did you try to print it?

Comment: YES, I tried.That prints the correct number I wanted.

Comment: Line 52, i don't know why you need it. Did you do anything in `scrollViewDidScroll`?

Comment: Oh,yes.I delate line 52, but still noting happens. I didn't do anything in scrollViewDidScroll.

Comment: It's hard to say anything else. I think you should show more code. Everything you did in your image is right ;)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that [tableView reloadData] is called somewhere after you return your data array with your [self dataArray] method. Do this since each cell's height is coming from a MXStatusModel object in your data array property.

It seems as though when initially trying to set the table view cell's height. The array is empty and therefore the model object does not have a height to return.

Comment: Sorry, I don't really understand. Cell height and some other frame are all setted as a property of my model. I think the frame and the cell height can get their value at the same time? Why do I need to reload my data?And if I have to, Where to do it?

Comment: Actually every time you call self.dataArray, you are calling the -dataArray method. You should declare dataArray as a property, rename your -dataArray method, and set the dataArray property within your newly named method - calling [self.tableView reloadData] immediately after.

Comment: That is why it does not work the first time but works thereafter. Another approach could also be calling  -reloadData after  '_dataArray = temp', but I recommend the former.

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
self.tableView.delegate=self;
self.tableView.datasource=self;
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

in your

```
viewDidLoad()
```

Comment: That doesn't work for me. In fact, this is my tableViewController and the datasourse and delegate are all inherited from its superclass.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to make your cell dynamic .You have to return UITableViewAutomaticDimension in heightForRowAtIndexPath

```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100.0
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }
```

If you are getting data from api calls make sure .You are reloading your tableview after status code = 200 and also getting Array from api,Your array count should be greater than 0 .